# Unexpected Coding Error on Arduino Uno R3

Tags: arduino, syntax-error

When I run this code it gives me an error, I am still a beginner so I don't know how to fix it.
[This is what I have written so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IVER.png)

Comment: Any tips on how to fix it would be nice

Comment: You need to post your code as part of the question.

Comment: "gives me an error" is a bit unspecific. Which error do you get exactly and what did you expect it to do instead?

Comment: It would also be nice if you could take the time to read, [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Stackoverflow help. :) At the very least, you should describe the error you are getting, quoting any error messages if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

Giving a look in your code, you missed to place some semicolons (;) at the end of some instructions, to be more specific you miss them in lines:

5
32
34
37
40

In line 9, you have to type "Serial.begin(9600);" instead "serial.begin(9600);"

On the last else, you forgot to enclose the instructions between "{}" and placing the '}' to close the void loop.

You are making reference to a routine named getVoltage, but I don't see it

Another issue that I can see is that you have to write with uppercase words like: OUTPUT, INPUT, HIGH and LOW

Please share more details once you be able to fix this observations